# Angular 2+ Browser Back Button doesn't reload child route

Tags: angular, browser-cache, angular-components, back-button, angular-router

When clicking the back button sometimes the previous page reloads everything as expected and sometimes the previous page does nothing as though it is cached.

There is no caching on the page. No varnish. I have no service workers and it's not a pwa. CDN caching is all turned off. I've tried it in Chrome with "Disable cache" selected with the inspector open.

This is not code specific, but more generally questions about Angular and page caching / routing / life cycles.

1. What makes components, etc load or not load when clicking the browser back button?
2. And is there a way to force the component load like an HTTP no-cache header would do with a non-SPA? (Ideally without some huge workaround.)

========

UPDATE:

The parent route AuthGuard and the app component ngOnInit do seem to run. But the page component does not get run. The pages are all set up as child routes. Any idea why the correct child route would not be triggered? (The AuthGuard is returning valid.)

Comment: the back-button NOT load anything (you can see if use F12)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. When I refresh the page it loads and when it goes via the router it loads. But when clicking the back button. It doesn't reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

> What makes components, etc load or not load when clicking the browser back button?

First of all, when the `Router` is initialized, the default behavior involves invoking the [`Router.initialNavigation()`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router_module.ts#L558-L560) method:

```js
if (this.isLegacyEnabled(opts)) {
  router.initialNavigation();
} else if (this.isLegacyDisabled(opts)) {
  /* ... */
}
```

which looks like [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router.ts#L899-L904):

```js
initialNavigation(): void {
  this.setUpLocationChangeListener();
  if (this.navigationId === 0) {
    this.navigateByUrl(this.location.path(true), {replaceUrl: true});
  }
}
```

`navigateByUrl` will schedule a new navigation and [`setUpLocationChangeListener`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router.ts#L911) will subscribe to the `Location` class:

```js
this.locationSubscription = this.location.subscribe(event => {
      const currentChange = this.extractLocationChangeInfoFromEvent(event);
      if (this.shouldScheduleNavigation(this.lastLocationChangeInfo, currentChange)) {
        // The `setTimeout` was added in #12160 and is likely to support Angular/AngularJS
        // hybrid apps.
        setTimeout(() => {
          const {source, state, urlTree} = currentChange;
          this.scheduleNavigation(urlTree, source, state, {replaceUrl: true});
        }, 0);
      }
      this.lastLocationChangeInfo = currentChange;
    });
```

With `Location.subscribe`, you can listen to [`popState` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event).

From MDN:

> The popstate event of the Window interface is fired when the active history entry changes while the user navigates the session history

and

> Note that just calling history.pushState() or history.replaceState() won't trigger a popstate event. The popstate event will be triggered by doing a browser action such as a click on the back or forward button (or calling history.back() or history.forward() in JavaScript).

So, when a `popState` event occurs, a new navigation will be scheduled. Now, based on my understanding, what decides whether the current route will be processed or not can be found in [these lines](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/57575e379fce9eb2367bfd48a8eb8be81f1d082c/packages/router/src/router.ts#L528-L532):

```js
// !this.navigated - is this the first navigation?
// t.extractedUrl.toString() !== this.browserUrlTree.toString() - is the URL we're about to navigate different that the current one 
const urlTransition = !this.navigated ||
  t.extractedUrl.toString() !== this.browserUrlTree.toString();

// this.urlHandlingStrategy.shouldProcessUrl - returns `true` by default
const processCurrentUrl =
  (this.onSameUrlNavigation === 'reload' ? true : urlTransition) &&
  this.urlHandlingStrategy.shouldProcessUrl(t.rawUrl);

if (processCurrentUrl) {
  /* ... go through the route config ... */
} else {
  const processPreviousUrl = urlTransition && this.rawUrlTree &&
    this.urlHandlingStrategy.shouldProcessUrl(this.rawUrlTree);
/* When the current URL shouldn't be processed, but the previous one was,
* we handle this "error condition" by navigating to the previously
* successful URL, but leaving the URL intact.*/
if (processPreviousUrl) {
  const {id, extractedUrl, source, restoredState, extras} = t;
  const navStart = new NavigationStart(
      id, this.serializeUrl(extractedUrl), source, restoredState);
  eventsSubject.next(navStart);
  const targetSnapshot =
      createEmptyState(extractedUrl, this.rootComponentType).snapshot;

  // what happens next: running guards, resolvers etc...
  return of({
    ...t,
    targetSnapshot,
    urlAfterRedirects: extractedUrl,
    extras: {...extras, skipLocationChange: false, replaceUrl: false},
  });
} else {
  /* When neither the current or previous URL can be processed, do nothing
  * other than update router's internal reference to the current "settled"
  * URL. This way the next navigation will be coming from the current URL
  * in the browser.
  */
  }
}
```

---

> And is there a way to force the component load like an HTTP no-cache header would do with a non-SPA? (Ideally without some huge workaround.)

I think setting `onSameUrlNavigation: true` will make it work.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the default angular setting is "this.onSameUrlNavigation = 'ignore';". I tried changing it to 'reload' (the two options that are allowed are: 'ignore', 'reload') in vendor.js and vendor.map.js, but it didn't really affect anything.

Comment: Have you tried setting it from ‘RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {...here...})’ as well? If still doesn’t work, if you could reproduce the problem in a Stackblitz or something similar, I’d gladly investigate it further

Comment: I've added an update in the original post which informs the situation a bit more.